# Update table based on reference values from another table

Tags: windows, sqlite

I have two tables structured like so:

```
Table1 (reference table)
| Name UNIQUE | Value(Double) |

Table2 (data table)
| Name1 | Name2 | Number(Int) |
```

I want to add 10 to the number in each row of Table2 where the value of Name1 (from Table1) is greater than the value of Name2 (from the Table1). How can this be done in Sqlite3?

Comment: What have you tried so far? You should post a code example of your best effort try, and data examples of before and after to help others point you in the correct direction.

Comment: If your just starting to learn the language there are a ton of great tutorials and code examples online. for example: http://www.sqlitetutorial.net/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use an `UPDATE` statement to do this. Unfortunately SQLite does not support using a `JOIN` clause in an `UPDATE` statement so you will have to emulate the `JOIN` within the `WHERE` clause like so:

```
UPDATE Table2
   SET Number = Number + 10
 WHERE (SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE Name = Table2.Name1) >
       (SELECT Value FROM Table1 WHERE Name = Table2.Name2);
```

Similar questions that might also help you:

[How do I make an update while joining tables on sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/773441/how-do-i-make-an-update-while-joining-tables-on-sqlite)

[Update with JOIN in sqlite](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270259/update-with-join-in-sqlite)

Comment: Thanks for providing a quick way to fetch values from tables, I could not find this in tutorials. I reached my objective in a little lengthy way by creating a work table where I inserted values of name1 and name2 by joining table1 on table2 then inserting subtraction into another column. The table2 had an id column to it so I inserted that as well in the work table and then finally update table2 for id values in work table having subtraction column >0.

Comment: While this method is more elegant in its command form and what I was looking for, in execution I found the temporary work table approach that I took before to be much quicker in execution. Updating a fairly large database, the first approach completed the update almost immediately while this one took a while to run through. Could be because I need to use multiple update statements with different comparison criteria causing it to re-fetch the values every statement that need only be done once in the work table approach. Perhaps there is a way to do update faster with this approach as well.

Comment: @rain32 you could try adding an index to the table over the Name and Value columns - but it does not surprise me that your method may be quicker.